# ¿Cómo cambiar los valores de la secuencia después de una acción?

Tags: sql-server

Me encuentro construyendo un Stored Procedure.
Quisiera saber cómo puedo cambiar la secuencia automática después de realizar una acción como eliminar o insertar.

Tengo una tabla llamada Secuencia en la que se muestra la secuencia de los registros por ejemplo.

```
          Campo            Secuencia
        TiendaCentro         3
        TiendaZapata         2
        TiendaBenitoJuarez   1
```

-Tengo esos datos, si yo inserto un nuevo registro la secuencia de todos debe cambiar, insertando "TiendaVicente", se debe posicionar como el primero y así sucesivamente

```
         Campo           Secuencia
         TiendaCentro         4
         TiendaZapata         3
         TiendaBenitoJuarez   2
         TiendaVicente        1
```

-Eliminando "TiendaBenitoJuarez"

```
          Campo           Secuencia
         TiendaCentro         3
         TiendaZapata         2
         TiendaVicente        1
```

-Sql

```
         if @bandera = 'insertar'
         begin
         INSERT INTO secuencia VALUES(@vs_valor1, @vs_valor2, GETDATE(), 'Secuencia')
         end

         if @bandera = 'eliminar'
         begin
         DELETE FROM secuencia WHERE id_carga = 547155
         end
```

Espero puedan apoyarme, gracias anticipadas.

Answer (score 4):

Guiandome solamente por tu ejemplo, podrias hacer algo asi:

```
UPDATE secuencia SET secuencia = secuencia + 1
```

Mas alla de esto, tenese que tener en cuenta que:

- Deberias agregar una condicion, para que no aumente la secuencia que acabas de agregar.
- Esto solo funciona si la secuencia es siempre mas 1, si no vas a tener que pasar otra variable con el valor del incremento.
- El orden en que ejecutas puede llegar a tener importancia, vas a tener que revisar eso tambien (por si alguno de los dos falla) o usar una transaccion.

Para el delete, el procedimiento seria un poquito mas complejo.

Primero, antes de hacer el delete, obtenemos la secuencia a una variable.

```
DECLARE @var1 int;
SELECT 
    @var1 = secuencia
FROM
    SECUENCIA
where
    id_carga = 547155
```

entonces en var1 queda la secuencia que vamos a eliminar.

Luego de eso, hacemos el DELETE

```
DELETE FROM secuencia WHERE id_carga = 547155
```

Y luego de eso, hacemos el update, pero agregamos una condición

```
UPDATE 
    secuencia 
SET secuencia = secuencia - 1 
WHERE secuencia > @var1 AND (las otras condiciones)
```

Comment: Sugerencia pavota, si se puede insertar `Secuencia` en `NULL`, el `UPDATE` podría hacerse así: `secuencia = ISNULL(secuencia + 1, 1)`

Comment: tambien insertar secuencia en 0 y te ahorras la llamada a la funcion :p

Comment: Absolutamente!!

Comment: Holaaa, muchas gracias por la ayuda, pero en el DELETE, si elimina el numero 2, la secuencia no podría aplicarse así, o poniendo secuencia = secuencia - 1 :( porque el orden de la eliminación podría variar

Comment: ¡¡Muchas gracias!!!, voy a aplicarlo :)

Comment: Otra cosa, soy  reciente en ésta comunidad,  no sé si debo abrir una nueva pregunta :(, pero, en caso contrario, por ejemplo, que el que se inserta la secuencia no sea la primera si no la última? de qué manera podría capturar el ultimo valor de secuencia? Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: @masha10 Leiste el [tour], si no lo hiciste, aprovecha y miralo.. En este caso me haces dudar, ya que seria casi el mismo caso que esta. por ahi aca necesitas una solucion mas completa. abre una nueva pregunta, y si es necesario, pone esta como relacionada.