# ¿Como usar trigger en mysql para que cuando elimine un registro cambie el valor de una columna de los otros registros?

Tags: mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Bueno lo que intento hacer es una consulta para que cuando se elimine un registro de la tabla "clase" el valor de la columna "contador" de los otros registros se reste 1 siempre y cuando la id del los registros sean mayor que la id del registro que eliminé.
Luego listare esa tabla en una pagina y las columnas que usaria serian :

```
      contador , nClase
```

Ya que si muestro la idClase y elimino registros los numeros salen en desorden:
   1 , 5 , 10 ,11 ,12 ,20,etc
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En vez que tener una columna con **contador**, no es mejor hacer que cada vez que ejecutas el `query` obtenga el valor contador? Por ejemplo: `SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS contador FROM clase`.

Comment: No, es que lo que quiero hacer con la columna "contador" es que  remplace la  "idClase" osea cuando voy a listar la tabla en una pagina que me muestre las columnas  :  contador , nClase , ya que si pongo  "idClase" y elimino un registro salen numeros en desorden :  1,5,10,etc

Comment: Si no es del todo necesario que tengas esa columna, te recomiendo que evites hacer eso. Podrías manejar ese "contador" que quieres como un número ordenado ya sea con lo que estés tomando ese query.

Comment: Estas solucionando un problema de la vista, pasandoselo a la base de datos, y no es productivo, ya que quien muestre eso facilmente puede agregar la numeracion ordenada. mas alla de eso, hay una respuesta similar a esto aca: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/141871/324

Comment: Si lo estás haciendo con PHP, puedes poner ese "contador" en el `array_fetch`. Pero para darte una mejor respuesta, necesitaría que muestres algo de lo que tienes hecho con PHP para la query.

Comment: Independiente de la lógica de tu programación (querer tener un ID forzado de cada registro), para poder responder a tu pregunta original, Luis, sobre cómo hacer un trigger que realice esta tarea, necesitamos ver los intentos que has hecho al respecto: ¿lo has intentado en PHP? ¿o ya sabes programar triggers en Mysql? Por favor, muéstranos lo que llevas hecho para poder guiarte.

Answer (score 0):

La columna contador en este caso es totalmente inecesaria, no es mas que un campo calculado que no aporta nada y además te traerá dolores de cabeza ya que no podrás garantizar la consistencia de los datos, si necesitas numerar los registros devueltos en una consulta puedes agregar un contador al vuelo:

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT a.*, (@rownum:=@rownum+1) contador
FROM  (SELECT @rownum:=0) t, `mi_tabla` a;
```

Puedes ver un ejemplo en funcionamiento [aquí](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb50e/1)

Ejemplo completo:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mi_tabla` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `rev` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `mi_tabla` (`id`, `rev`, `content`) VALUES
  ('1', '1', 'text 1'),
  ('2', '1', 'text 2'),
  ('6', '2', 'text 3'),
  ('9', '3', 'text 4');

SELECT a.*, (@rownum:=@rownum+1) contador
FROM  (SELECT @rownum:=0) t, `mi_tabla` a
ORDER BY a.id;
```

Resultado:

```
| id | rev | content | contador |
|----|-----|---------|----------|
|  1 |   1 |  text 1 |        1 |
|  2 |   1 |  text 2 |        2 |
|  6 |   2 |  text 3 |        3 |
|  9 |   3 |  text 4 |        4 |
```